# Syncing music from a Mac to a Windows

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

I recently changed from a Mac back to a PC.  I transferred all my music via bluetooth to my new computer.  The new machine will play all my music, but it will not sync with my iPhone.  Any advice?

Comment: Can you provide some more details around the "will not sync" part? What software are you using to sync, is there any error message etc?

Answer (score 1):

Try sync with [iTunes](http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/) for Windows.